# How to Identify a button that doesn't get identified through Android uiautomateviewer?

Tags: java, android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to automate an Android app with Android UIAutomator. When i tried to identify objects via android uiautomateviewer it doesn't list details of all the objects on the page, rather it gives me the details of the main frame. Buttons that are located inside that frame does not capture through Android uiautomateviewer.

**Question**: Is there are way to identify buttons that were located inside that frame ?

Can we use UiSelector method for this purpose? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Is the a web app or a web page? If so, UiAutomator can't read those.

If it's a normal app (it happened to me with one app I had on my phone), then it's a problem with the app itself (not sure what exactly).

In order to **fully answer your question**: if it's not visible/detected by UiAutomatorViewer then it's not visible/detected by UiAutomator.

One example of this: when a pop-up is opened we usually can still see the contents behind it. However, for UiAutomatorViewer and UiAutomator, that pop-up is the only thing that's currently on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the respond Inês. In this care the objects are located in a webview. Hence, cannot locate using UiAutomatorViwer.